# Connecting to SQL Server in PySpark

Tags: python, docker, pyspark

Currently, I've got my PySpark python script in a Docker container, which is using the jupyter/pyspark-notebook image.

I've downloaded the Microsoft JDBC driver (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).
I've copied and renamed mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11.jar file to the tmp folder in my Docker container (mssql-jdbc.jar).

However, my PySpark script keeps failing with the following error when I run it within the container "py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26.jdbc.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

```
spark_conf = SparkConf().setAppName("PortfolioPerformance").set("spark.jars", "/tmp/mssql-jdbc.jar")

    # Create the SparkSession with the configured SparkConf.
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=spark_conf).getOrCreate()

    database_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://my_server;databaseName=Fusion"
    properties = {
        "user": "my_user",
        "password": "my_password!",
        "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    }

    df = spark.read.jdbc(
        url=database_url,
        table='SELECT * FROM my_query',
        properties=properties
    )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if you don't specify the jar package in your runtime docker, Any script execution won't be able to find the objects. You. need to install it properly.

Comment: Why not use `pyodbc` ?

Comment: So I need to specify it in the Image?

Comment: Pyodbc doesn't seem to be supported by PySpark

Comment: Why do you think so? [link](https://medium.com/@madtopcoder/pyodbc-on-spark-8d84cdde4359)

Comment: Ok, I'll have to check it but based on what I was reading, it wasn't natively supported.